# Matlab Plot that changes with time

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot a figure that changes with time (think of it as plotting the shape of a pole as the wind passes through it, so I want to plot the shape at every second).

To avoid the x axis limit changing frequently I want to fix it to the limits (max and min that I calculate before plotting). Here is a sample of my code:

```
for i=1:1:numberofrows
    momentvaluesatinstant = momentvalues(i,:);
    figure(1)
    plot(momentvaluesatinstant,momentheader)
    drawnow
    title(sprintf('Moment profile along pile at time 0.2%f',time(i)'))
    xlabel('Moment (kN.m)')
    xlim([momentvalues(rowminmoment) momentvalues(rowmaxmoment)])
    ylabel('Length of pile (m)')
    delay(1);
end
```

Although I am specifying the limits of the x axis to be fixed to the values I specify, the plot keeps changing the limits depending on the data being plotted? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39059154/2627163) for a more compact and correct way to animate things in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it, need to add `xlim manual`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you needed `xlim manual`, but here is a more compact and correct way to animate your data:

```
% use 'figure', `plot` and all the constant parts of the figure only once, before the loop.
figure(1)
m = plot(momentvalues(1,:),momentheader); % plotting only step 1
xlim([momentvalues(rowminmoment) momentvalues(rowmaxmoment)])
xlabel('Moment (kN.m)')
ylabel('Length of pile (m)')

% loop from step 2 ahead
for k = 2:length(momentvalues)
    pause(1); % use pause to set the delay between shots
    % use 'set' to change the x values
    set(m,'Xdata',momentvalues(k,:));    
    drawnow
    title(sprintf('Moment profile along pile at time 0.2%f',k))
end
```