# How can I make these point move frequently each second, since the Euclidean distance between these points is updated each time interval?

Tags: matlab

I deployed number of random points with their speed and displacement, how can I make these point move frequently each second,
since the Euclidean distance between these points is updated each time interval (second)  based on the coordinates of new positions?

```matlab
NumNode=2;
ro=1000;
center=[0 0];
Initial_Direction = rand(NumNode, 1) * 2 *pi; v = 15/3.6; % [m/s] velocity of node
theta_Node=2*pi*(rand(NumNode,1));

% let the Nodes deployed away from the center of circle network layout
g = 0.5 * ro + 0.5 * ro * rand(NumNode,1);
PosNode_x=center(1)+g.*cos(theta_Node); % Initial positions
PosNode_y=center(2)+g.*sin(theta_Node);
PosNode = [PosNode_x ,PosNode_y];

DX2 = [cos(Initial_Direction(:)) .* v,sin(Initial_Direction(:)) .* v]; % displacement of Node
PosNodeNew = PosNode + DX2; % New position of node without rotating
rotaion2 = [cosd(Initial_Direction), -sind(Initial_Direction); sind(Initial_Direction), cosd(Initial_Direction)]; % Rotation matrix to make the movement of node similar to move on arc

% Index approach to multiply different matrix dimensions
index=1:numel(PosNode);
xyRotated1 = rotaion2;
xyRotated1(index)= rotaion2(index).*PosNode(index); % rotated matrix multiply by position of node
index2 = 1:numel(DX2);
Newposss=xyRotated1;
NewPosss(index2) = xyRotated1(index2) + DX2(index2);
gg= NewPosss(index2);    % New position of node with rotating on arc

figure(1)
scatter(PosDrone_x,PosDrone_x,'r+')
figure(2)
scatter(PosDroneNew(:,1),PosDroneNew(:,2),'b*')
figure (3)
scatter (xyRotated1(:,1),xyRotated1(:,2),'r.')
axis equal
figure (4)
scatter(NewPosss(1,:),NewPosss(1,:),'b*')
axis equal
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're doing, but it does sound like you need a `for` loop with a `drawnow()` command. Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225669/5211833), with a `pause(1)` to update every second

Comment: Actually I want to move these points each time  interval I tried to use for loop but doesn't work ! the most important I want the distance between these nodes get updated with time due to its important in my work